# how to connect MS Access (x86) DB using Microsoft Jscript running in x64 bit Environment

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to connect an MS Access (x86) database (*.mdb) from a third party application which is x64 bit and supports Microsoft JScript ...
My Code Looks like below:
function testaccess(sender : System.Object, cmdArgs : Ico.Gwx.CommandExecutionEventArgs)
{
    try
    {

```
    strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\EC_SCADA\\Configurations\\ModbusEthernetConfig\\EC_ModbusOPC_Config.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"; 
    var cnn = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;
    var cmd = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand;
    var qr1 : String = "Select IPAddress from Devices where Name = 'Machine1'";
    var da : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter;
    var dt : System.Data.DataTable;
    //MessageBox.Show("Variables defined");

    cnn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
    //MessageBox.Show("cnn defined");
    cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(qr1, cnn);
    //MessageBox.Show("cmd defined");

    da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    cnn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened");
    da.Fill(dt);
    MessageBox.Show("Code End");        

}
catch (e)
{ MessageBox.Show("OOPS!!! something went wrong, Kindly try again!!!!");
}
```

}
First of all the Code editor itself throws error at line "da = new..." as "More than one constructor matches this argument list"

Can anyone help on this??

Comment: If I ignore the code editor error as mentioned above about "More than one constructor..." and TRY To execute the code in runtime, it just fails at the line "cnn.Open()"
Also to note that, I did not get intellisense when I typed cnn.Open() in code editor. Generally, if I type "cnn." it should show me Intellisense - thus I feel something wrong in connection definition

Answer (score 0):

I found couple of issues here. 
[1] missed to define dataTable like 
"dt = new System.Data.DataTable"
[2] I downloaded and installed "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable - 64 bit" from Below link, installed on my computer and the code just works fine. 
[https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255]